# Is going (simply going as a tourist) to temples or churches or christian masses, shirk or kufr?

Tags: practical-islam, shirk, kufr

Is going (simply going as a tourist) to temples or churches or christian masses, shirk or kufr.
Also, to what extent can a Muslim participate in the practices of other faiths.

**Assuming the Muslim participant has 100% complete faith in Islam and no faith whatsoever in other faiths , *at all*.

Comment: If a non-Muslim enters a mosque as a tourist is he somehow becoming a Muslim?

Comment: Shirk is an action, not just a belief, so participating in any practice related to shirk of another faith is shirk.

Comment: @TheZ: Source ?

Comment: "Whoever disbelieves in Allah after his belief... except for one who is forced while his heart is secure in faith. But those who [willingly] open their breasts to disbelief, upon them is wrath from Allah, and for them is a great punishment;" (16:106)
Only one exception given. Also, this verse proves that disbelieving in God is an action not just belief.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is not, unless you worship like christians. We accept their religion, just believe that it is degenerated.

Comment: Can you please quote the source?

Answer (score 1):

If the person had “100%” faith in Islam like you proposed, by what Islamically driven logic would he be compelled to visit a venue of kufr and shirk. “Tourism” implies some sort of recreation, that the church or synagogue or temple, etc, is a place of interest to the visitor.

For a person who has “100%” faith in Islam, what interest is there in being inside of an establishment that is in open rebellion to Allah and his pure Deen of Islam?

There is no justification for a Muslim to participate in the practices of other faiths in any circumstance. Allāh says in Surah al Maida, that he has perfected and chosen the religion of Islam for humanity. There is no mention of any other way of life being accepted or given validation by Allāh or His Messenger Sallallahu Alayhi Wasallam.

No other Deen or way of life is accepted by Allāh subhannahu ta ala but Islam. To willingly participate or indulge in the practices of the kuffar is kufr. To willingly visit the establishments that these practices take place for any purpose other than the clear-cut, unapologetic, unabashed, uninterrupted establishment of Islam, is kufr.

And Allāh knows best.